# An algorithm problem: Finding number of 'steps' needed to move from one city to another

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to write a program. Usecase is to find number of 'step' required to move from a source city to a destination city, where a step means moving from one city to another. So its like one of those friend graph applications on social media.

My approach is like this:

```
# start with step=1
# Find  cities accessible directly from source city, add their name to queue(with step=1 appended to name)
# Iterate the queue(check queue is not empty OR DB operations still pending)
  # if city has not been verified earlier(using Set)
    # update verified city Set
    #check if city name contains destination city name
      # if yes, extract step value from name, and exit
      # else, find accessible cities for city(run DB operations on a separate thread) and add to queue(with city name )
```

I am using Java executor service to run DB operations in parallel.

This works and I get correct results. But program is slow.

What modifications can be done algorithmically to improve performance?

Comment: Your algorithm is BFS. You can use bi-directional search (executing BFS from both ends)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Potentially there are couple of improvements that you can consider based on the dataset size you are dealing with.

- As @MBo mentioned in the comment, you can use bi-directional BFS to reduce the overall complexity of finding the destination.
- You are iterating over the queue using a single thread, is that correct? If so, you can consider applying a parallel queue in this place.
- There is another way to improve the BFS by applying [Direction-Optimizing approach](https://scottbeamer.net/pubs/beamer-sc2012.pdf). You can find an model implementation of this approach [here](https://github.com/sbeamer/gapbs/blob/master/src/bfs.cc).